Basic question relating polarization in the Stark Shift
I hit a snag when trying to answer this very basic question: Is the quadratic Stark effect, in a spherically symmetric Hamiltonian, independent of the linear polarization of the electric field?
It seems like everywhere where the Stark shift is discussed it is assumed that the electric field goes in the z-direction. I always thought that the other directions would be identical due to the rotational symmetry of the problem.
But recently I tried calculating Stark shifts for different hydrogen orbitals with an x-oriented field and a y-oriented field and got a different answer compared to the z-oriented field for all states except $s$ states.
So, the question is as posted above: Should this be linear-polarization independent? Is there a formal way to prove this?
Thanks in advance.

You should show your calculation results at least. But should be clear that you should be having calculational mistakes. Did you diagonalise your Hamiltonian with the new E fields?
